# switching an embedded vimeo to an embedded youtube video

Tags: html, css, iframe, youtube, vimeo

Hello I currently have an embedded vimeo video the code is below, I need to switch it to a video on youtube could somebody please show me how?

Below is my code.

Thanks in advance

```
<ul class="bxslider">
<li>
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/4415083?api=1;title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=d01e2f&amp;autoplay=1" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's almost exactly the same. You can find the embed code by right clicking on the video and "Get embed code".

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/0Y860aUcclY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```